# Way to DistinctBy will remove duplicates from a repeating id but if the value is null will leave the duplicates?

Tags: c#, linq

There is a way to prevent duplicates Id, but if id is null to let the list to be with duplicates null?

```
data = data
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.DocVersionNumber)
  .DistinctBy(x => x.RequireId)
  .ToList();
```

in this way if I have few items with null on `RequireId`, only one will stay.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```js
var temp = data.Where(x => x.RequireId == null).ToList();
data = data.Where(x => x.RequireId != null)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.DocVersionNumber)
  .DistinctBy(x => x.RequireId)
  .ToList();
data.AddRange(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data
  .Where(i => i.RequireId != null)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.DocVersionNumber)
  .DistinctBy(x => x.RequireId)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: no it will remove all the null values from data

Comment: @bob2habanay so what exactly do you want? i dont understand what you're asking for

Comment: if Id is null allow, if id !=null distinct by the id